# How does it different stand by vs standing by in these sentence?

Tags: grammar

This sentence came from Charlie and the chocolate factory.
Reading a story, I came up with a question. How should I imagine the situation when the father stands by the door vs standing by the door. If it is the same situation, can I say stand by the door or standing by the door? Thank you in advance.

> father would come in as well, and stand by the door, listening to the stories that the old people told.

vs

> father would come in as well, and **standing** by the door, listening to the stories that the old people told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the sentence after "and" needs to have a finite verb.  So there are two options.  The original by Dahl, or

> father would come in as well, and, standing by the door, listen to the stories that the old people told.

This alternative means the same, but it doesn't flow as well.  There is an isolated "and". The participle is intrusive, rather than flowing.  Dahl's version reads much more smoothly.